# tool to align the objects and get its coordinates of a pygame/turtle game?

Tags: pygame, 2d-games, python-turtle

Is there any tool to easily place objects and get the desired coordinates of the objects.
It is difficult to calculate the coordinates for each objects of the game.

tool i'm asking is to place some objects like rectangle or some image in the window of WIN_HEIGHT,WIN_WIDTH  then get the **coordinates** of those objects placed.

Answer (score 0):

For `pygame.Rect` you can use `rect.height` and `rect.width`(there are also `.top`, `.bottom`) to get desired results. If you have `pygame.Surface` objects, than you can call these methods to get the results:

[Pygame surface documentation (get_methods)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html?highlight=height#pygame.Surface.get_height)

Comment: In MS PowerPoint when we move a text box it clings to the center or aligns itself with other text boxes in the slide, in similar fashion is there any tool which aligns the rect object(other objects too..),so finally i can just get the coordinates of it and use it in my program.

Comment: I am not familiar with something like that in pygame. But you can make function that for example takes two arguments (pygame.rect) and aligns second one with the first one by correcting x or y coordinate. Maybe to put the list of `rects` for the second argument and then it could align the whole set of objects. No doubt there are better solutions, this is just an idea, maybe you find it useful